# select data for particular month and year sqlite xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, sqlite, date

Having some problems to retrive data from sqlite hope you guyz can help me out ,

So , Let me describe my problem here ,

```
CREATE TABLE ex_manager (ex_id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,ex_title text,ex_amount text,ex_description text,ex_category text,ex_date DATE ,ex_upload_date DATE, ex_image text)
```

This is the query used to create a table ,

Table have date feild ex_date with DATE datatype ,

Now , i insert date with format yyyy-MM-dd like ,

```
NSDate *today=[NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *df=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    NSString *datestring = [df stringFromDate:today];
```

and the query i execute is:

```
query= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into ex_manager1 (ex_title,ex_amount,ex_description,ex_date,ex_category,ex_upload_date,ex_image) values ('%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@')",_ex_title.text,_ex_amount.text,@"abcd",_ex_date.text,_ex_category.text,datestring,path ];
```

And , I can successfully able to add data to the database ,

and i want to retrive data for particular month and year .

I run the query like

```
SELECT * FROM ex_manager where strftime('%Y%m',ex_date) = '201502'
```

and no data are there in result .

Can anyone please guide me how should i create db and insert value and how to retrive data for particular month and year by selecting and passing it in query .

Thanks in Advance . and it will be very helpful for me ,please help me out .

Comment: Are you sure the data successfully inserted ?

Comment: yes , i can retrive them by select * from ex_manager

Answer (score 1):

`dd-MM-yyyy` is not one of the [supported date formats for time strings](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), so the return value of `strftime()` is always NULL.

Use `yyyy-MM-dd` instead.
(In that case, you can also avoid calling the `strftime` function and use `WHERE ex_date GLOB '2015-02*'` instead, which would allow the database to use an index for the search.)

Comment: That's what I wrote …

Answer (score 0):

I think may be there was an issue with inserting data, try to replace this line may be help you.

```
query= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into ex_manager1 (ex_title,ex_amount,ex_description,ex_date,ex_category,ex_upload_date,ex_image) values (\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\")",_ex_title.text,_ex_amount.text,@"abcd",_ex_date.text,_ex_category.text,datestring,path ];
```

Comment: SQL string delimiters are `'`.

Comment: This was also conflict that string complete...like @"insert into.....'some string'", the delimiters ' working like string complete at 'some..' thats why \"%@\" is better to use '%@'..

Comment: Strings can contain both `'` and `"` characters.